# Given a curve $\alpha$, how can one derive a formula for the normal vector $N_{\alpha}$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, differential-geometry, vectors, frenet-frame

Let $\alpha:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable curve such that $\alpha '(t)$ and $\alpha ''(t)$ are linearly independent for every $t$. Let

$$s:=\int_{t_0}^{t}|a'(u)|du$$

and $\beta = \alpha \circ s^{-1}$, that is, $\beta$ is an arc length parametrization of $\alpha$.

---

One defines the Frenet Trihedron of the curve $\beta$ as

$$T_{\beta}(t):=\beta'(t)$$
$$N_{\beta}(t):=\frac{T'_{\beta}(t)}{|T'_{\beta}(t)|}=\frac{\alpha''(t)}{|\alpha''(t)|}$$
$$B_{\beta}(t):=T_{\beta}(t)\times N_{\beta}(t)$$

---

My goal is to derive a Frenet Trihedron for the curve $\alpha$, so as to not need $\beta$. Deriving the tangent vector $T_{\alpha}$ is easy enough, since we would like $T_{\alpha}(t)=T_{\beta}(s(t))$, thus

$$T_{\alpha}(t):=T_{\beta}(s(t))=\beta '(s(t))=\frac{\alpha '(t)}{|\alpha '(t)|}$$

yet I have trouble deriving the normal vector $N_{\alpha}$. I begin with

$$N_{\alpha}(t):=N_{\beta}(s(t))=\frac{T'_{\beta}(s(t))}{|T'_{\beta}(s(t)|)}=\frac{\left(\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\alpha'(t)}{|\alpha'(t)|}\right)}{\Big|\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\alpha'(t)}{|\alpha'(t)|}\Big|}$$

A couple of applications of the chain rule give me

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\alpha'(t)}{|\alpha'(t)|}=\frac{\alpha'(t)\cdot \alpha''(t)}{|\alpha'(t)|^3}$$

so that

$$N_{\alpha}(t)=\frac{\alpha'(t)\cdot \alpha''(t)}{|\alpha'(t)\cdot \alpha''(t)|}$$

yet this seems wrong, since it is possible for $\alpha$ to be an arc-length parametrization, in which case $|\alpha'(t)|=1$ and $\alpha'(t)\cdot \alpha''(t)=0$ so that $N_{\alpha}(t)$ would not be well defined.

---

$1.$ What did I do wrong?

$2.$ How could a formula for the normal vector $N_{\alpha}$ be derived?

Comment: How did a vector turn into a scalar (dot product) when you differentiated it? And why are you referring to the quotient rule as the chain rule?

Comment: Isn't $\alpha(t) \in \mathbb{R}$? If so, any two non-zero vectors (i.e. numbers) will always be linearly dependent.